# How to access exceptionPayload in Flow

Tags: java, exception, mule, mule-flow

I have been looking for this on Google but couldn't find a solution.

How can I access the exceptionPayload in the the mule flow
like I can access the payload #[message.payload].  In the same way is there any way I can have the exceptionPayload also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `#[exception]`, which is `null` if there is no exception payload for the current event.

Comment: Thank you. What class does this object belong to. Like #[message] belongs to MessageContext. Does this exception belongs to any class? Also I don't see any details related to this exception object on the Mule Expression Language page. Where can I find more details about this?

Comment: It doesn't belong to any class: it's bound as a top level variable directly by `org.mule.el.mvel.MessageVariableResolverFactory`. The doc is wrong unfortunately, it shows `exception` under `message`. But we have it right in Mule in Action :D